# Android bigger and always visible scrollbar for WebView

Tags: android

I d like a bigger and always visible scrollbar for my WebView

i am in minSDK 3, version 1.5

step 1: this codes not working: (the scrollbars disappear after a while)

```
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
```

(`android:fadeScrollbars="false"` not worked too, in that api level not usable)

step 2: how can i make a bigger scrollbar?

Answer (score 3):

add  `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` in your xml activity...it will be working fine..!

Answer (score 0):

If its important to create a bigger scrollbar you could extend ScrollView and use computeVerticalScrollOffset() to position a custom drawable in another view represting the overlaying scrollbar down the side. Could be a bit of work but you could fully customise it all.